# Make numpy matrix with insufficient length of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have some data, say a list of 10 numbers and I have to convert that list to a matrix of shape (3,4). What would be the best way to do so, if I say I wanted the data to fill by columns/rows and the unfilled spots to have some default value like -1.

Eg:

```
data = [0,4,1,3,2,5,9,6,7,8]
>>> output
array([[ 0,  4,  1,  3],
       [ 2,  5,  9,  6],
       [ 7,  8, -1, -1]])
```

What I thought of doing is

```
data += [-1]*(row*col - len(data))
output = np.array(data).reshape((row, col))
```

Is there a simpler method that allows me to achieve the same result without having to modify the original data or sending in `data + [-1]*remaining` to the `np.array` function?

Comment: What's the background of your question? Is it that `data` is huge and you want to avoid making unnecessary copy?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there are various ways of doing this.  My first inclination is to make a `output` array filled with the 'fill', and copy the `data` to it.  Since the fill is 'ragged', not a full column or row, I'd start out 1d and reshape to the final shape.

```
In [730]: row,col = 3,4
In [731]: data = [0,4,1,3,2,5,9,6,7,8]
In [732]: output=np.zeros(row*col,dtype=int)-1
In [733]: output[:len(data)]=data
In [734]: output = output.reshape(3,4)
In [735]: output
Out[735]: 
array([[ 0,  4,  1,  3],
       [ 2,  5,  9,  6],
       [ 7,  8, -1, -1]])
```

Regardless of whether `data` starts as a list or a 1d array, it will have to be copied to `output`.  With a change in the total number of characters we can't just reshape it.

This isn't that different from your approach of adding the extra values via `[-1]*n`.

There is a `pad` function, but it works on whole columns or rows, and internally is quite complex because it's written for general cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.ndarray.flat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) to index into the flattened version of the array.

```
data = [0, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 9, 6, 7, 8]
default_value = -1
desired_shape = (3, 4)
output = default_value * np.ones(desired_shape)
output.flat[:len(data)] = data

# output is now:
# array([[ 0.,  4.,  1.,  3.],
#       [ 2.,  5.,  9.,  6.],
#       [ 7.,  8., -1., -1.]])
```

As hpaulj says, the extra copy is really hard to avoid.

If you are reading `data` from a file somehow, you could read it into the flattened array directly, either using `flat`, or by reshaping the array afterward. Then the data gets directly loaded into the array with the desired shape.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the solutions given based on speed. The tests was done using IPython 4.2.0 with Python 3.5.2|Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit).
The data array starts with 100,000 elements. The new dimentions are 150,000 x 150,000.

#### M. Klugerford's solution (icreasing the data and reshaping):

```
%timeit data = [x for x in range(100000)]; col=15000; row=15000;  data+= [-1]*(row*col-len(data)); output = np.array(data).reshape((row, col))
```

> 1 loop, best of 3: 38.8 s per loop

#### Psidom's solution (using np.pad):

```
 %timeit import numpy as np; data = [x for x in range(100000)]; col=15000; row=15000; np.pad(data, (0, row * col - len(data)), 'constant', constant_values = -1).reshape(row, col)
```

> 1 loop, best of 3: 20.4 s per loop

#### Praveen's solution (using np.ndarray.flat):

```
%timeit import numpy as np; data = [x for x in range(100000)]; col=15000; row=15000;  output = -1 * np.ones((col, row)); output.flat[:len(data)] = data
```

> 1 loop, best of 3: 12.2 s per loop

#### hpaulj's solution (create output first; coping later and **best solution so far!!**):

```
%timeit import numpy as np; data = [x for x in range(100000)]; col=15000; row=15000; output=np.zeros(row*col,dtype=int)-1; output[:len(data)]=data; output = output.reshape(col, row)
```

> 1 loop, best of 3: 6.28 s per loop

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `numpy.pad`, pad the data with -1 at the end of array and then reshape it:

```
import numpy as np
data = [0,4,1,3,2,5,9,6,7,8]
row, col = 3, 4

np.pad(data, (0, row * col - len(data)), 'constant', constant_values = -1).reshape(row, col)

# array([[ 0,  4,  1,  3],
#        [ 2,  5,  9,  6],
#        [ 7,  8, -1, -1]])
```